# Mask using Multicolor Movieclip

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm working on a project where I need to have multiple movieclips on top of one another with the topmost object being the only one seen, aside from spots for aesthetics. I tried creating an instance of the topmost movieclip and assigning it as a mask to the one below, but because the mask is made of multiple fill colors (an issue I've seen online), the end result has huge sections where the mask didn't work and in general doesn't behave like it should.

Are there any good alternatives for making the mask, or work-arounds to make this work?

Comment: Would you be able to post some screenshots of what you currently have?

Comment: Why not just hide everything but the top one?    You could use the `LAYER` blend mode on the common parent, and then `ALPHA` or `ERASE` blend mode on the mask, then it will just use the transparent pixels as the mask.